# How to mock only the authorize() method in Form Request on Laravel 5.1?

Tags: unit-testing, laravel, mocking, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

We are implementing **resource ownership** and/or **input validations** through the use of `FormRequest`. Our controller tests are functional test so we don't mock `Request` but use the `$this->call($method, $url, $params, ...)`.

The issue is that `FormRequest` is a subclass of `Request`. Is there a way to mock only the `authorize()` method but keeping the rest of the `Request` object non-mocked?

If so, how to?  I already tried partial mocking with `Mockery` and it either didn't work or I did it wrong.

```
$this->mock(\Namespace\Http\Requests\CustomRequest::class . '[authorize]')
    ->shouldReceive('authorize')
    -> .......
```

Answer (score 0):

Use phpunit mocking system instead of Mockery.

```
$request = $this->getMock(\Namespace\http\Requests\CustomRequest::class, ['authorize']);
$request->expects($this->once())->method('authorize')->willReturn(true);
```

hope it helps;

Comment: In laravel 5.6, I'm getting `Error: Call to undefined method Tests\...\XxxTest::getMock()`

Comment: @YevgeniyAfanasyev for php 5.6+ and PHPUnit 7.5+ do this

`$request = $this->getMockForAbstractClass(MyFormRequest::class, ["authorize"]);

$request->expects(self::once())->method("authorize")->willReturn(true);
`

Comment: @ClaudioLudovicoPanetta `TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request::__construct() must be of the type array, string given`

Comment: @YevgeniyAfanasyev that's odd, I've that specific snippet in one of my test and it works. I let you know if I can find a fix